# Read Avro File one line at a time . Python

Tags: pyspark, avro

Context:
I want to read Avro file into Spark as a RDD. I want to know whether it is possible to parse the Avro file one line at a time if I have access to Avro data schema .

I am using pyspark for writing my spark jobs . I am thinking about using sc.textfile to read in this huge file and do a parallel parse if I can parse a line at a time . Any pointers towards parsing Avro file one line at a time would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: This will help you, https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/gettingstartedpython.html . But, spark has lazy evaluation probably you wont need that

Comment: If you want to process file one line at the time the you shouldn't use Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is meant for Big data processing with multiple partition of files in parallel and reading single line at time can not be spark use case.

You can add your business logic with the help of row transformations (apply on each row) and spark will execute lazily.